# "Drop objects not in source" not honored

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, schema-compare

I'm attempting to use Schema Compare in SQL Server Data Tools to update my project from a database. I deselected "Drop objects not in source" setting but SSDT continues to drop objects that are not in the source (database).

I've tried it with tables and procedures, and I've tried it in the reverse direction (database updating project), as well as database updating a different database, but in every case, objects that do not exist in source are still dropped.

When I open the .scmp file the setting appears to be correct:

```
<PropertyElementName>
  <Name>DropObjectsNotInSource</Name>
  <Value>False</Value>
</PropertyElementName>
```

I'm using SSDT Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise. I'm on version 17.6.4.

Comment: We have the same issue and have not found a solution unfortunately

Comment: Drops can be caused by transitive dependencies which are somehow linked to both objects in the project and in the DB. If you make a minimal repro it'd be great. And please clarify: do yo see those drops in visualization only or in generated script as well?

Comment: I see these in the generated script and also in a direct database update.